# Why is my ButtonClickListerner not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I followed a tutorials on how to make a TicTacToeGame, but I wanted to add something from myself: the restart(ten) and exit(eleven) button(in my code they are called ten and eleven). So I added those in the class "ButtonClickListener" but they don't work.

My MainActivity.java:

```
package com.wouter.testjk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.wouter.testjk.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mHumanCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mAndroidCount;

    private int mHumanCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mAndroidCounter = 0;

    private boolean mHumanFirst = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;




    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);






        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener(this);



        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mHumanCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humancount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mAndroidCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);

        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame();


    }


    private void startNewGame()
    {
        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));

        }
        if (mHumanFirst)
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
            mHumanFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
            int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
            setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
            mHumanFirst = true;
        }
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;



        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

    }



    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player,location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
        {
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
        case R.id.ten:

            startNewGame();
            return;

        case R.id.eleven:

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            return;

        }


        if (!mGameOver)
        {
            if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
            {
                setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                if (winner == 0)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                    int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                    setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                    winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                }
                if (winner == 0)
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                else if (winner == 1)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                    mTieCounter++;
                    mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                    mGameOver = true;
                }       
                else if (winner ==2)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                    mHumanCounter++;
                    mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                    mGameOver = true;
                }
                else if (winner ==3)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                    mAndroidCounter++;
                    mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                    mGameOver = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't my buttonclicklistener not working? You deliberately want it to not work? Or did you mean "Why is my ButtonClickListener not working?"

Comment: Ow, sorry my bad, I ment "Why is my ButtonClickListener not working" I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified that your MainAcivity implements OnClickListener. This means that your code needs to implement the methods specified in OnClickListener, which you have done at the end of your code with the following code block;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

But as you can see, you've not actually done anything in this code block.

You've also created a private class called ButtonClickListener which also implements OnClickListener, but when you use the setOnClickListener method on your buttons, you are not assigning an instance of your ButtonClickListener. All you are doing is assigning `this` which is your MainActivity class, which you are then casting to OnClickListener which is also redundant since MainActivity already implements OnClickListener.

---

**Edit** (see comments) Here's the rearranged code.

```
package com.wouter.testjk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.wouter.testjk.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mHumanCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mAndroidCount;

    private int mHumanCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mAndroidCounter = 0;

    private boolean mHumanFirst = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener(this);



        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mHumanCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humancount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mAndroidCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);

        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame();

    }

    private void startNewGame()
    {
        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));

        }
        if (mHumanFirst)
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
            mHumanFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
            int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
            setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
            mHumanFirst = true;
        }
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                        setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                        winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    }
                    if (winner == 0)
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                    else if (winner == 1)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }       
                    else if (winner ==2)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                        mHumanCounter++;
                        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner ==3)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                        mAndroidCounter++;
                        mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player,location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
        {
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.ten:

            startNewGame();
            return;

        case R.id.eleven:

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is a cleaner solution. I should Maybe delete my answer as it is a bad example and was just meant to make your code work...

Comment: okay I think im starting to understand it a little bit, so my private class buttonclicklistener has only 5lines of code left?

Comment: @ChrisCarneiro, no your answer is also a valid approach. I only meant that my example code might be a cleaner solution than goedkoop's code.

Comment: @goedkoop, I removed the private class ButtonClickListener altogether. On further inspection I see you had a constructor in you private class , which you used to set a `location` variable. I'm guessing this is used elsewhere in your code for other buttons? Edit your question to also show where you are using this constructor, and we may be able to come up with a solution that meets both needs.

Comment: I actually get a few errors when I use Sounds Conception's code.  One of them is "location cannot be resolved to a variable", should I put the "ButtonClickListener(int locatoin)" also in the "public void onClick(View v)"?

Comment: Okay I see, I will just upload the whole mainactivity.java

Comment: @SoundConception I tend to think that inner classes should be avoided especially in this particular case where either implementing the interface (like you did) or by using the anonymous inner class approach are more commonly used for that purpose.

Comment: @ChrisCarneiro I agree. I'd like to see how goedkoop is using this location variable, and maybe come up with a way to achieve what is needed without the private inner class

Comment: @goedkoop. Thanks for the updated listing. Ok a quick fix would be to move the `if (!mGameOver)` logic back into your private ButtonClickListener class, but as @ChrisCarneiro said, it might be better to get rid of your private inner class ButtonClickListener eventually.

Comment: Thank for helping me out btw, this fixed a few errors. I got this error left though: The type MainActivity.ButtonClickListener must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.OnClick(View). this sounds weird to me

Comment: Yes, your `if (!mGameOver)` needs to be inside the `public void onClick(View v)` method of your ButtonClickListener class. When you say ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener you are actually saying it will Override onClick.

Comment: To summarise. You will have an onClick in your ButtonClickListener class which contains the `if (!mGameOver)` logic, and an onClick in your MainActivity which handles the two other buttons. It's a little messy and part of the reason we're suggesting getting rid of the inner ButtonClickListener method eventually.

Comment: Okay, so i basically got 2 onClick classes? I know its very messy, but I just started with java so it's a bit hard for me. If you have time for it, could you update your code above with everything in it?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, this makes it pretty clear. I am understand it better and better. The only error that is left is: "view cannot be resolved" in the public void onClick(view v) in the  main

Comment: Please add the LogCat of this error to the end of your question.

Comment: Yes it does. It says the problem is on line 166. It can't resolve the View called `view`. Our onClick is defined as `public void onClick(View v)`, but in the switch statement we have `switch (view.getId()`. We should use the same name in both locations rather than have `v` in one and `view` in the other. Have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

The listener you set on the mTen and mEleven button is your activity.

The thing is there's no implementation of the `onClick()` method in it.

If I get what you want to do, in order to make your mTen and mEleven button clicks to be handled by the `ButtonClickListener`, you must instantiate it first and then set it on the buttons.

Maybe like this:

```
ButtonClickListener mButtonListener = new ButtonClickListener();
mTen.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
mEleven.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener;
```